# why is slick carousel not working with browserify?

Tags: jquery, browserify, slick.js

I'm trying to use slick carousel (http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) and installed via npm.

Including it via browserify like this:

```
slick = require('slick-carousel')
```

trying to run like this:

```
$('.gallery__carousel').slick();
```

No console errors, carousel not initialising. What's going on?

Comment: Please checked package.json file.
slick-carousel is installed or not?

Comment: seems not installed, but why? It seems to be applying some classes to my dom elements...

Comment: Installed 1st then use "slick-carousel" function. You are requring the file but not installed "slick-carousel", then how you can access the functions.

Comment: I did run 'npm install slick-carousel' and it said: 'slick-carousel@1.5.5 node_modules/slick-carousel' so why is it not installed then?

Comment: Check your node_module folder, slick-carousel folder is present or not?

Comment: Please check here https://www.npmjs.com/package/slick-carousel

Comment: I did check there, but can't see anything useful?

Comment: If it is possible then create demo for same.

Comment: hm this'll be tricky as it's a browserify related issue... ? Or any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

> NOTE: It's not recommended to edit library. If still in case you want
>   a workaround then you can follow like below.

I also had the same problem with using slick with browserify but none of solutions worked for me. Then i take a took into slick.js and changed -

Find:

```
(function(factory) {
    'use strict';
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define(['jquery'], factory);
    } else if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
        module.exports = factory(require('jquery'));
    } else {
        factory(jQuery);
    }

}(function($) {
```

Replace:

```
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {
```

add the last line -

Find:

```
}));
```

Replace:

```
})( jQuery, window, document );
```

Hope it helps to understand the problem.

Comment: Can you rewrite it, It is so confusing replace what with what.

Comment: @nofel try pull latest slick carousel and author might fixed that. If still not fixed then open slick carousel and find the code block as per i mentioned and delete that and paste respective code like above.

Comment: Can u filter your code. It's really hard to understand if I should find all of chuck of code and replace it with small bit or how?

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs thanks to this code of Slick v1.5.x:

```
(function(factory) {
    'use strict';
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define(['jquery'], factory);
    } else if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
        module.exports = factory(require('jquery'));
    } else {
        factory(jQuery);
    }

}
```

Author assumes, that if you use CommonJS module loader (like Browserify), you should have had jQuery in you dependencies (it's called directly with `require('jquery')`).

I prefer this solution:

1. Add jQuery as NPM dependency: `npm install --save jquery`
2. Make it global, e.g. with [browserify-shim's export global](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim#you-will-sometimes)
   or with: `window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');`
3. Then you can safely require Slick with `require('slick-carousel');`

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this problem another way. There is npm package `slick-carousel-browserify`.
So:

```
npm install slick-carousel-browserify --save-dev
```

And:

```
$ = require ('./../../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js');
slick = require('slick-carousel-browserify');
slick($('.selector'));
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add
`$ = require('jquery')`
before
`slick = require('slick-carousel')`

it works for me.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer and explain **why** this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
"browserify-shim": {
"jquery": "global:jQuery",
     "slick-carousel": {
      "depends": [
        "jquery: jQuery"
      ],
      "exports": "$.fn.slick"
    }
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
     "browserify-shim"
    ]
  }
```

Comment: then use as import slick from 'slick-carousel'

Comment: You should add an explanation of why this is the answer.