# Use slick-carousel with global jQuery and browserify

Tags: jquery, browserify, slick.js, browserify-shim

My setup looks just like [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33558223/trouble-including-slick-carousel-with-global-jquery-using-browserify-browserif) with browserify-shim and the depends all set up. I'm not getting the issue reported in that question where Browserify is complaining that it can't find the module.

Rather, on page load, I get `Uncaught TypeError: $picker.slick is not a function`, `$picker` being a jQuery object. Hoping I can find a definitive solution.

[This solution changes code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30592650/why-is-slick-carousel-not-working-with-browserify), so ideally we don't do that. There's also [this solution for a similar issue but using browserify global transforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26024912/shimming-dependencies-of-dependencies-with-browserify-shim/26596279#26596279). Right now I've got my browserify settings in my `package.json` and I'm not sure how to translate that.

Also, I'm using [Elixir's](https://laravel.com/docs/master/elixir) abstraction of gulp browserify, though not in a Laravel project. WordPress, actually.

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly exporting Slick Carousel as a jQuery plugin, like so:

```
"browserify": {
  "transform": [
    "browserify-shim"
  ]
},
"browserify-shim": {
  "jquery": "global:jQuery",
  "slick-carousel": {
    "depends": [
      "jquery: jQuery"
    ],
    "exports": "$.fn.slick"
  }
},
```

Comment: Looks like I'm still getting `Uncaught TypeError: $picker.slick is not a function`